# Android Google Maps V2 - create object movement player on map using historical position data set - Map limiations of data and upate interval?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

So I am embarking on a project that involves the following:

I have a set of location data for a certain period of time, which location data can be from multiple objects or single object. I am trying to create something similar to a playback map where the user can play all object's movement from a certain period ( think of a music player and how you can move progress bar).

Question:

**Is there any limitation in this where the Map API won't be able to handle so much updating or not being able to handle such amount of data displayed on the map?**

I am sorry if the question seems to broad but I am just trying to understand the limiations before I begin working on this project.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? I know Google Earth does it through an Intent, so I am guessing this is possible with Google Maps v2 APIs.